# Deleting Specific Product Option Using Shopify API

Tags: python, shopify, shopify-api

Using the Python ShopifyAPI library, version 12.3.0 I want to delete a specific product option.

def remove_product_option(self, product_id):
product = self.get_product_by_id(product_id)
option_name = self.config['option_to_delete']

```
    for i, option in enumerate(product.options):
        if option.name == option_name:
            product.options.pop(i)
            product.save()
```

This code is not working. There are no error messages, but the product.save() returns false. What can be the problem, and how can I fix it?

Edit:

It appears like you cannot delete a product option if it has values. The solution would be to manually delete the option using the Online Store, because as far as I could find there is no way to do this with the API.

Answer (score 0):

It appears like you cannot delete a product option if it has values. The solution would be to manually delete the option using the Online Store, because as far as I could find there is no way to do this with the API.